# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSPasteboardWriting'

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am getting this error

Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSPasteboardWriting'

i have created the class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ErrorLog : NSObject<NSCoding, NSPasteboardWriting, NSPasteboardReading> {

}

@end
```

Can any one tell me that whether i am missing some header file or whats the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

NSPasteboardWriting is Available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later.
check your project setting(Base SDK).

Answer (score -1):

Import the header file in which `NSPasteboardWriting` and `NSPasteboardReading` protocols are declared. Also make sure you have the `protocols` in the class specified.

Comment: Can you tell me which files are that if you know i tried to find out but unsuccessful...